# Could not proxy request /api/user from localhost:3000 to http://localhost:3000/

Tags: reactjs

I am new to React.  I'm not sure where to start on this.   I am getting the following error when trying to post:  Proxy error: Could not proxy request /api/user from localhost:3000 to http://localhost:3000/.
[1] See https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors for more information (ECONNRESET).

Here is my server.js file:

```
var cors = require("cors");
var express = require("express");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var methodOverride = require("method-override");
var PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;
var app = express();
var Sequelize = require("Sequelize");
var passport = require("passport");
var session = require("express-session");
var env = require("dotenv").load();
const routes = require("./routes");

// Requiring our models for syncing
var db = require("./models");

// Add routes, both API and view
app.use(routes);

// Creates connection with Sequelize
const connection = new Sequelize("live_work_chill_db", "root", "password", {
  host: "localhost",
  dialect: "mysql",
  operatorsAliases: false
});

// Create instance of cors with Express
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(express.static(process.cwd() + "/public"));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(methodOverride("_method"));

// Initialize passport, express session and passport session
app.use(
  session({
    secret: process.env.PASSPORT_SECRET,
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true
  })
); // session secret
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session()); // persistent login sessions

// // Routes - Import our auth.js file
// var authRoute = require('./controllers/auth.js')(app,passport); // Added passport as an argument to pass its functionality to auth.js

// load passport strategies
require("./config/passport/passport.js")(passport, db.Users);

// Syncing our sequelize models and then starting our express app
db.sequelize.sync({ force: false }).then(function() {
  app.listen(PORT, function() {
    console.log("App listening on PORT " + PORT);
  });
});
```

Here is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "mern",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "if-env NODE_ENV=production && npm run start:prod || npm run start:dev",
    "start:prod": "node server.js",
    "start:dev": "concurrently \"nodemon server.js\" \"npm run client\"",
    "client": "cd client && npm run start",
    "install": "cd client && npm install",
    "build": "cd client && npm run build",
    "heroku-postbuild": "npm run build"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^4.1.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.18.7"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "bcrypt-nodejs": "^0.0.3",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "express-session": "^1.15.6",
    "if-env": "^1.0.4",
    "method-override": "^3.0.0",
    "mysql2": "^1.6.4",
    "passport": "^0.4.0",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "react": "^16.8.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "^2.1.3",
    "sequelize": "^4.42.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this into your package.json

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:3000",
```